# I want to identify a click on google ad on my website and want to perform some javascript on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to identify a click on google ad on my website and want to perform some javascript on click function. Basically i want to hide the ad once user click on google ad.

Answer (score 1):

The best way, I feel is to wrap the ad/plugin/elem around an element (be it a div) and then setup a eventlistener for click event for those div(s) (if multiple, using classes) and catch that event and hide it.

Hope that helps!